# Creating Shopify Order Over Graphql

Tags: flutter, api, graphql, shopify, graphql-mutation

I have a Mobile app made with flutter and when a client wants to place an order it opens Webview checkout,
my question is how to create an order with cash on delivery over Graphql to avoid opening Webview
I searched in docs but I did not find a suitable mutation for doing that

solution to avoid opening webview checkout

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Draft Order and once you're happy with it, convert it to a real order. At that, the order really exists, and the merchant will have to collect the money as they can, when they can, and deal with the fulfillment etc. Pretty standard stuff.